# javascript document.write vs jQuery replaceWith

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some pages that will use the path portion of the URL to place text on the page, like so..

```
urlPath=window.location.pathname; 

urlPathArray = urlPath.split('/'); 


urlPath2=urlPathArray[2]; 
if (urlPath2 == "sometext")
    {
    document.write("Title for Some Text")
    }
else if (urlPath2 == "othertext")
    {
    document.write("Title for Other Text")
    }
else 
    {
    document.write ("Generic Title")
     }
```

Is it worth figuring out how to do this with jQuery and the replaceWith function?

Comment: It's worth figuring out how to do it without `document.write`.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a div or some other container with an ID like so:

```
<div id="content"></div>
```

and then use javascript DOM manipulation to populate it:

```
urlPath=window.location.pathname; 

urlPathArray = urlPath.split('/'); 

var oput = document.getElementById("content");

switch(urlPath2)
{
  case "sometext":
    oput.innerHTML = "Title for Some Text";
    break;
  case "othertext":
    oput.innerHTML = "Title for Some Other Text";
    break;
  default:
    oput.innerHTML = "Default Text";
}
```